# I try to run xampp on localhost but xampp keeps redirecting me to web server

Tags: php, sql, xampp, prestashop

Well, I have an issue with my localhost.

We have a website hosted at https://papaki.com and I came with the idea to download all the contents of the public_html file and place them to Htdocs (so that I can make changes locally before I upload them to the Web) and so I did.

I also took the entire database and imported it in my PhpMyAdmin, I run the query and everything seemed fine(took 2 hours or so :) ).

Created a user, granted him all privileges on the DB and configured  to connect to the DB and then I went to see if it will work.

Typed localhost:81/prestashop on my browser (that's the directory, and also changed the port of xampp because it was interfering with another app) and it redirected me to the online Web server https://somon.gr and not on localhost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: Did you do a quick search on `move prestashop site` and find [this little bit of documentation](https://www.prestashop.com/en/blog/how-to-migrate-prestashop-to-a-new-server)

Comment: did you make changes in **ps_shop_url** table in your db

Comment: Thank you for replying :).

RiggsFolly I have done everything stated on that page.

Sachin no I haven't should I change something on ps_shop_url.
there are some tables in there 
id_shop_url int(11) unsigned --> 1
id_shop int(11) unsigned --> 1
domain varchar(150) --> www.somon.gr
domain_ssl varchar(150) --> www.somon.gr

Comment: I changed domain varchar(150) --> www.somon.gr to :
localhost:81/prestashop 
&
domain_ssl varchar(150) --> www.somon.gr to :
localhost:81/prestashop 
but nothing happened